# Vim shows incorrect theme in error

Tags: vimrc, vimscript, colorscheme

Basically, all I'm trying to do is enable the syntax option.

```
syntax enable
colorscheme cobalt2
```

For some reason, I get no errors if I comment out the first line, but in case I don't comment it, I get:

```
Error detected while processing /usr/share/vim/vim81/syntax/synload.vim:
line   19:
E185: Cannot find color scheme 'cobalt'
```

which is not exactly the name of the theme that I'm trying to use.

Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: It looks like if you disable syntax, then it doesn't do the color highlighting scheme anyways.  If `syntax enable` is commented out, do you still get any colorscheme when you open a file in ViM?  If you do `ls /usr/share/vim/vim81/colors`, that will display a list of all available color schemes you have available to you.  Maybe double check the one you want exists?

Comment: Hey @Vee, `cobalt2` exists and I'm able to apply it after commenting out the `syntax enable` as mentioned above.

Comment: What's strange though, is the fact that the error message displays the incorrect theme name, which of course, does not exist.

Comment: Well, in looking at my own `synload.vim`, line 19 is `exe "colors " . colors_name`.  Since I don't have the cobalt color scheme, when I'm in vim and I type `:colors cobalt` I get the same error you see.  I did a grep for the variable `colors_name` in `/usr/share/vim/vim81` and got all the colors .vim files defining that global variable.  Can you confirm that your `/usr/share/vim/vim81/colors/cobalt2.vim` defines the `colors_name` variable as `cobalt2`?

Comment: Welcome to [vi.se]!

Comment: Glad to be here @D.BenKnoble!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's important that a theme set the `g:colors_name` variable correctly to match the name of the theme script file, because Vim will use it when it needs to reload the theme (and it does so in a few situations.)

I could find at least one `cobalt2` theme online that had a commit fixing it from incorrectly setting the variable to `cobalt`, to setting it correctly as `cobalt2`.

See [this commit](https://github.com/GertjanReynaert/cobalt2-vim-theme/commit/df3f65df526ec96990f561792462ddde363204df), which is the latest commit in theme `cobalt2` available as Vim package `GertjanReynaert/cobalt2-vim-theme`.

It's the latest commit of that repo, but it's dated of over five years ago, 2015, so I'm not sure how you would end up with that repo but an older version of that...

In any case, try to update your `cobalt2` theme to the latest. If you're already on the latest, look inside the `colors/cobalt2.vim` script inside it and see how it sets `colors_name`. If it sets it incorrectly, you can fix it there (and hopefully report it to the maintainer of the source where you got it, so it can be fixed there too.)

Comment: That looks like the other piece of the puzzle.

Comment: That is some Sherlock-level sleuthing right there. Works now, thanks!